# How to hide an iad

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, iad

I have an iAd, and when somebody taps the ad I want it to hide. How could I do this without getting the "an ad is obscured" error in the debug? Thanks in advance

Comment: Isn't tapping the ad supposed to trigger interaction with the ad, not hide it?

Comment: This sounds like an easy way to guarantee that your app fails the review process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you maybe mean that you want hide ads after the user has clicked on one and finished with whatever interaction has to take place?

if so, after the ad has completed you should just be able to hide the iAd view.  But if you are looking to hide the interactive bit of it then you probably won't pass the review process and you might want to try another ad service that would better suit your needs.